# Meaning of “short"

Tags: sentence-meaning, slang, military

In the end of the movie *Full Metal Jacket*, a person name Joker was saying:

> I am happy that I am alive, in one piece and ***short***.

What does *short* mean here?

Comment: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/alive-in-one-piece-and-short.3379858/

Comment: @laugh: I wouldn't have understood the usage without your link. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Fumblefingers, I've added an answer. But I wouldn't have known either.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this reference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/alive-in-one-piece-and-short.3379858/) (addressing the same quote), "short" in military slang means that a person is about to finish his tour of duty and expects to return home soon.